# Lua pattern matching: problem specifying the pattern to match

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, design-patterns

I am attempting some pattern matching in Lua and have hit a small problem. I am trying to match everything from the first newline character in my data up to the following pattern `_\x0C`.

here is the code that has the problem:

```
configmatch = string.match(response, "\n(.+)(['_\x0C'])")
```

it seems to be working some of the time, other times it is "cutting short" the expected output. the problem is probably to do with this: (['_\x0C']) but i have been unable to resolve it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is `\x0C` intended to represent four characters or a single character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `_\x0C` literally in the string, you need to use `"\n(.-_\\x0C)"`. If you mean *underscore* followed by *formfeed*, use `"\n(.-_\012)"`, because there are no `\x` escapes in Lua (5.1).

Comment: That works perfectly, i needed the pattern literally in the string. Thank you